# Jquery to display default css

Tags: jquery, css

Hi please take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/pwjNQ/1/

I am trying to figure out how to get the default/current css values to be used when you hold down the "preview recommended style" text, - only when held down,

and then if the user likes the recommended style they can click the "use recommended style" to default the settings to match the css/preview.

My problem is the actually css will be changed by other functions, so sometimes the color would be black as recommended and sometimes red as recommended.  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a demo that will alter the style values with mouseup/mousedown.
you can view it using this jsfiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/yCnxw/

it should help get you started to your ultimate solution. edit the demo to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For stuff to happen only while the mouse is held down, use `.mouseDown()` and to revert back, use `.mouseUp()`

Also, instead of arrays of fonts and colors, I'd define a class each in your CSS for the various options and them add those classes to the preview element.